# How to get result from Mono<String>

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'am not very familiar with reactive programming , but have a problem to deal with.

For example:
I have an entity

```
public class PersonDTO {
    private String personName;
    private String personDepartment;
}
```

And this repository

```
@Repository
public interface PersonEntityMongoRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<PersonEntity, String> {

    Mono<Person> findByUserPrincipalNameIgnoreCaseAndIsActiveTrue(String userPrincipalName);

}
```

Then I have the following logic:

```
personMongoRepository.findByUserPrincipalNameIgnoreCaseAndIsActiveTrue(principalName)
                        .subscribe(person -> {
                            personDTO.setPersonDepartment(person..getDepartment());
                        });
```

After this I have some logic that depends on PersonDTO.personDepartment field.
But this code can be lunched before Mono is done and line  personDTO.setPersonDepartment(person.getDepartment()) is executed

So, how can I get result from Mono , in order to have not null  PersonDTO.personDepartment field in next code steps?

Comment: It's very hard to answer the question correctly without knowing the context. How do you use this DTO? Is it part of some REST API? Although nothing happens without subscribe you should avoid calling it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Make your "logic" subscribe on this mono.

Or

Execute your "logic" inside subscribe body.

```
personMongoRepository.findByUserPrincipalNameIgnoreCaseAndIsActiveTrue(principalName)
                        .subscribe(person -> {
                            personDTO.setPersonDepartment(person..getDepartment());
logic.start();
                        });
```